# pgadmin4 fails to start on fedora 27

Tags: pgadmin-4

(pgadmin4:10053): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:8645:2: Junk at end of value for padding-left

(pgadmin4:10053): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:13132:11: 'shadowbox' is not a valid property name

Can someone please help figure out why? Also help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! All, I had to do was enable a shell extension "Topicons plus" from gnome tweak.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on F27 (running Mate) and had similar problems. For me, initially, it seemed to be a user elevation issue (that problem appears to have gone away). I could start it if I opened up a terminal window, typed 'sudo pgadmin4', enter. However, I always had some kind of failure (usually about connection) when trying to start it from the menu.

What I finally discovered was to set the following command in the pgadmin4 menu properties: 'kdesu -u  -c /usr/pgadmin4/runtime/pgAdmin4' (you may have to install kdesu). Now it works great!