# pgAdmin4 Doesn't Start After PostgreSQL Config

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I tweaked the `hba_conf` file to use username and password authentication rather than ident on `local` and `ipv4` local connections and then I noticed that pgAdmin doesn't start up at all. I'm not sure if I changed anything else.

I tried to start pgAdmin from the terminal with elevated privileges and that doesn't help either. I used the following command.

```
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/pgadmin4
```

I get the following output

```
[106968:107001:1004/233100.612004:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[106968:107001:1004/233100.612156:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[107010:107010:1004/233101.233521:FATAL:nw_content_renderer_hooks.cc(53)] Failed to load node library (error: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
#0 0x7f0b18d6f703 (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4da3702)
#1 0x7f0b18d8389e (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4db789d)
#2 0x7f0b1dd78505 (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x9dac504)
#3 0x7f0b1ddde788 (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x9e12787)
#4 0x7f0b18d2c94e (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4d6094d)
#5 0x7f0b18d29f11 (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4d5df10)
#6 0x7f0b18d2a90c (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4d5e90b)
#7 0x7f0b15f2db11 ChromeMain
#8 0x7f0b13dbbb75 __libc_start_main

Received signal 6
#0 0x7f0b18d6f703 (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4da3702)
#1 0x7f0b18e058a1 (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4e398a0)
#2 0x7f0b13f97a20 (/usr/lib64/libpthread-2.33.so+0x13a1f)
#3 0x7f0b18e04b55 (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4e38b54)
#4 0x7f0b18d83d1f (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4db7d1e)
#5 0x7f0b1dd78505 (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x9dac504)
#6 0x7f0b1ddde788 (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x9e12787)
#7 0x7f0b18d2c94e (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4d6094d)
#8 0x7f0b18d29f11 (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4d5df10)
#9 0x7f0b18d2a90c (/usr/pgadmin4/bin/lib/libnw.so+0x4d5e90b)
#10 0x7f0b15f2db11 ChromeMain
#11 0x7f0b13dbbb75 __libc_start_main
  r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 00007ffceba67e40 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000246
 r12: 00000000000000b8 r13: 00007ffceba69170 r14: 00007ffceba69180 r15: 00007ffceba69188
  di: 0000000000000002  si: 00007ffceba67e40  bp: 00007f0b13f598f0  bx: 00007f0b13579200
  dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007f0b13dd12a2  sp: 00007ffceba67e40
  ip: 00007f0b13dd12a2 efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
 trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
[106999:106999:1004/233101.732637:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(376)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

I tried to look online and here, but I'm not really sure what to look for. I am running Fedora 34 Workstation, the command `uname -a` gives me this.

```
Linux fedora-laptop-hp 5.13.16-200.fc34.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 13 12:39:36 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I did look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205036/pgadmin4-fails-to-start-on-fedora-27) question, but it doesn't apply to my situation.

==== EDIT ====

As requested, here is the content of my `pg_hba.conf` file.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

==== EDIT 2 ====

I should also mention I am able to start `psql` and the `postgresql` service through `systemctl` and `service` and interact with PostgreSQL just fine.

Comment: You must have changed something in the pgAdmin configuration. Please describe what.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Well hard question without the facts: `pg_hba.conf`. You might have deleted some standard configuration setting(s) that are required for PostgreSQL to start. Any chance you could supply the `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: @JohnK.N. Thank you for replying. As requested, I have updated my post with the contents of the file.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe While I don't remember making any changes to my pgAdmin configuration, I will be glad to share it if you can tell me how I may obtain it.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this?